# Change browser add-on icon and data, according to active tab

Tags: crossrider, browser-addons

Currently, I have a crossrider add on consisting of an extension.js and a background.js

In the extension.js, I send a GET request to the page which the user is currently on. In this GET request, I am collecting some data.

I am storing the domain name (protocol + domain) in a local Crossrider Database, and for every get request, I am making sure that the domain being requested is not present in the database, and if it is found in the database, I am preventing the request from occurring (for optimisation purposes).

Now, the problem is that I want it so that every time the user changes their tab, the browser add-on icon and data presented (e.g. browserAction Icon Label) to the user is changed  **respective** to the domain they are currently on, within that tab.

For example:

Tab 1 - https://www.google.com
Tab 2 - https://www.yahoo.com

When a user is on Tab 1, the browser add-on icon and details change respectively to that URL. As soon as he/she switches to Tab 2, the details are changed again respective to the URL they are on. If a user visits a new website in the same tab, the details of the browser add-on, should again be respective to the new URL they have visited.

Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of your requirements, as you nicely described them, are comprised of 2 components that can be addressed in the background scope using the following Crossrider methods:

1. To detect tab changes use [appAPI.tabs.onTabSelectionChanged](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.tabs-method-onTabSelectionChanged).
2. To monitor URL changes use [appAPI.webRequest.onBeforeNavigate](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.webRequest.onBeforeNavigate)

To simplify the code, I would use a common function for the button updates. So for example, in the *background.js* file your code would look like:

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {
    // Monitor tab selection changes
    appAPI.tabs.onTabSelectionChanged(function(tabInfo) {
        // tabInfo.Id = Tab Id
        // tabInfo.tabUrl = URL in tab
        updateButton(tabInfo.tabUrl);
    });

    appAPI.webRequest.onBeforeNavigate.addListener(function(details, opaqueData) {
        // details.pageUrl = URL of the tab requesting the page
        // opaqueData = data passed to the context of the callback function
        updateButton(details.pageUrl);
    });

    function updateButton(url) {
        // Your code to update the button based on URL
    }
});
```

[**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]